# What is the error in this code?

Tags: database, sql-server-2005

I want to delplay the row in the richtextbox

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MOSTAFA\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=company;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("select * from data where id='"+textBox1.Text+"')",con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader read = com.ExecuteReader();
        if (read.Read())
            richTextBox1.Text = "id" + read[0].ToString();
        else
            label3.Text=("The client didn't found");
    }
```

Comment: Do you get an error?  What is not working?

Answer (score 2):

There's an error in your generated query.  You have a closing parenthesis without an opening one.  The line as you have it would produce:

```
select * from data where id='sometest')
```

which will yield a syntax error from SQL Server.

Try this instead:

```
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("select * from data where id='"+textBox1.Text+"'",con);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra parenthesis in that SQL statement.

**But more importantly, you are leaving yourself wide open for SQL Injection.  To get around this devastating and easily avoidable issue is to use parameterized queries.**